# Express API Patch date returning null in Prisma

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, patch, prisma

Here is my issue: I have a `PATCH` API request that is replacing the existing `dateofbirth` entry to `null` in my `PostgreSQL` table, when not providing `dateofbirth` in the `PATCH` body (when editing other fields (`firstname`) for example).

In my `PostgreSQL` `Customers` table, the `dateofbirth` field is of `datetime` type.
The `Prisma` function below written in `typescript` performs an `Update` to my `PostgreSQL` Customers table:

```
  export async function editCustomer(id: number, customerNewInfo: {firstname: string, lastname: string, email: string, dateofbirth: string}) {
    await prisma.customers.update({
   where: {
    id: id
  },
      data: {
        firstname: customerNewInfo.firstname,
        lastname: customerNewInfo.lastname,
        email: customerNewInfo.email,
        dateofbirth: new Date(customerNewInfo.dateofbirth)

      },
    })
  }
```

As you can guess, the `new Date(customerNewInfo.dateofbirth)` is actually passing null to `Prisma` when I do not provide the `dateofbirth`. If I take out `new Date()` then I get an error on the database side, saying that the field is of `datetime` and I provided a `String`.

How can I enforce the `dateofbirth` `datetime` type, while at the same time not replacing the existing entry with `null` when sending a `PATCH` API call ?

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is wondering, here is the solution:

```
dateofbirth: customerNewInfo.dateofbirth != null ? new Date(customerNewInfo.dateofbirth) : undefined
```

This is from the Prisma Documentation:

> Setting a field value to undefined is the same as not including the
> email field in the update query at all

Source: [Prisma Client Documentation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/null-and-undefined)